# Polymers paper toggle button jumps back to unchecked

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

i bower installed polymers paper-toggle-button element and use it as:

```
<paper-toggle-button></paper-toggle-button>
```

it look as it should but when i click on it, it doesn't toggle. and when i drag and let go, it jumps back. Same happens with the buttons in paper-toggle-button/demo/index.html from the bower_components.
Do i miss some other dependencies or have i to implement an onclick handler to toggle the checked attribute myself?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="line"><span>No</span><paper-toggle-button on-change="_toggleChanged" checked class="orange"></paper-toggle-button><span>Yes</span></div>
```

Then handle the change:

```
_toggleChanged: function(event){ if(event.target.checked){ console.log('i was toggled:' +event.target.checked)};
```

Comment: didn't work. the on-change event was never submitted when i click or drag the toggle. although on dragging, i get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: this._userActivate is not a function"

Comment: Would you post more of your code where this._userActivate comes from?

Comment: i found the problem. 
instaling the paper element i used the download as bower option from the elements catalog web page. which gave me this:  

    bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-toggle-button#^1.0.0 

and i had the said toggle issue. now i tried with 

    bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-toggle-button. 

and bower asked me to choose the version ("2) paper-toggle-button#~1.0.11 which resolved to 1.0.11") and now every thing works. but thanx for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

instaling the paper element i used the [Polymer catalog's](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-toggle-button?view=docs) download option with bower. which was:

```
bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-toggle-button#^1.0.0
```

i assume it loades newer version of it dependencies which aren't compatible with it. Then i tried:

```
bower install --save PolymerElements/paper-toggle-button
```

and bower let me pick a version:

```
 2) paper-toggle-button#~1.0.11 which resolved to 1.0.11
```

and now everything works fine.